# i can print out the python list using 'print' but cannot use return

Tags: python

I am unable to use the `return` function to print the final value. My code:

```py
    def filter_wave(wave,n):
        new_wave = [i for i in wave]
        for k in range(n):
            for i in range(len(wave)):
                curr_wave = new_wave.copy()
                if(i==0):
                    new_wave[i] = int(curr_wave[i]*0.6+curr_wave[i+1]*0.2)
                elif(i>0 and i<len(wave)-1):
                    new_wave[i] = int(curr_wave[i-1]*0.2+curr_wave[i]*0.6+curr_wave[i+1]*0.2)
                else:
                    new_wave[i] = int(curr_wave[i-1]*0.2+curr_wave[i]*0.6)
        print(new_wave)
```

After iterating `n` times, it should return the final wave. `print()` works, but if I try `return`, it doesn't work. What is the error?

[Image of successful `print()`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HjoV.png)

[Image of unsuccessful return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvpoJ.png)

Comment: Please show us some example input data. Are you using `return new_wave` or `return(new_wave)`?

Comment: after return you are print function or not like `print(filter_wave(wave,n))`

Comment: I have added pictures of what output i get when using return and print

Comment: im using return new_wave

Comment: Unless using interactive python session, what command/function returns is not printed on the screen unless explicitly told to... hence what @soheshdoshi said.

Comment: i dont understand what you mean Ondrej. What is interactive python session

Comment: filter_wave(original_wave_sample, 200)  This is how they call the function in the test facility and my function is supposed to return the list. but whenever i use return new_wave, nothing displays in the output and the test facility keeps returning an error,

Comment: @BalajiHariharan when you are calling return, are you doing anything with that value? Also, both images are using `print()`

Comment: @PioKozi  no, im not doing anything with it, just returning. I have edited the image

Comment: @BalajiHariharan you need to print your result. So if you're piping the result from the function into a variable, print that variable.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, if you call the function by running the line

```
filter_wave(original_wave_sample, 200)
```

you want the output to be equal to the printed variable new_wave

When you print your variable with print() in the body and no return statement the variable is printed to your screen. If you use return(new_wave) then you will have to specify a variable in which the returned variable new_wave will be stored:

With the return(new_wave) in your function:

```
result = filter_wave(original_wave_sample, 200)
print(result)
```

Full example:

```
 def filter_wave(wave,n):
    new_wave = [i for i in wave]
    for k in range(n):
        for i in range(len(wave)):
            curr_wave = new_wave.copy()
            if(i==0):
                new_wave[i] = int(curr_wave[i]*0.6+curr_wave[i+1]*0.2)
            elif(i>0 and i<len(wave)-1):
                new_wave[i] = int(curr_wave[i-1]*0.2+curr_wave[i]*0.6+curr_wave[i+1]*0.2)
            else:
                new_wave[i] = int(curr_wave[i-1]*0.2+curr_wave[i]*0.6)
    return(new_wave)

result = filter_wave(original_wave_sample, 200)
print(result)
```